# Ldapsearch to ldapjs conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, ldap

I've been trying to convert the following [ldapsearch](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch) query

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.berkeley.edu -x -b 'ou=people,dc=berkeley,dc=edu' objectclass=*
```

to an [ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/) script:

```js
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var server = 'ldap://ldap.berkeley.edu';
var searchBase = 'ou=people,dc=berkeley,dc=edu';

var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: server
});

var opts = {
  filter: '(objectclass=*)'
}; 

client.search(searchBase, opts, function(err, res) {
  res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
    console.log(entry.toString());
  });
});
```

The ldapsearch gives me plenty of results but ldapjs doesn't return any users.
You can find some attempts of solving this on [GitHub](https://github.com/christianv/berkeleydir/blob/3087a7f6bc3f7ea369dc51979fff531ed0625103/ldap.js).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ldapjs search scopes are "backwards" of OpenLDAP and (AFAIK) most similar C libraries that are derived from the UMich code.  The default scope in ldapjs is "base", as opposed to "sub".  Without seeing any of your data, you probably need to make that code look like:

```
var opts = {
  filter: '(objectclass=*)',
  scope: 'sub'
}; 

client.search(searchBase, opts, function(err, res) {
  res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
    console.log(entry.toString());
  });
});
```

Comment: Adding `scope: 'sub'` did the trick, thank you. Also thanks for explaining how this exactly works.